# My ToastWallet account is hacked. What to do please?

Tags: wallets, bitcoin, passphrase

My toast wallet was hacked. I had forgotten my passphrase. I need help desperately. I forgot my passphrase and noticed a few days ago over 25K xrp has been withdrawn in 5 transactions past, respectively. The transactions have been made to three distinct destinations.

Q1) If someone has/guess our passphrase and had the PIN number already, can change the passphrase? What about the PIN?
Q2) If someone changed the passphrase can we know the whereabouts of the person who did it?
Q3) Can we tell the where about the location or the person where my bitcoins where transferred to. I have the "To address" and "Destination Tag" of the transaction details?
Q4) How can we officially pursue this. I am the official owner of the account? can I file a lawsuit? Can I hire a lawyer? Where should I start from, please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is gone. Nothing can be done. I'm sorry, such is the architecture of blockchain. To know where it went just google your wallet. On similar ethscan site for your wallet. This will not reveal anything more than the wallet it went to.

To make it completely clear, there is nothing legally or even illegally that can be done. You lost your funds.